# Have endgame tablebases ever been compiled for smaller variants of chess?

Tags: chess-variants, tablebases, computer-chess

I am interested in compiling endgame tablebases for a few miniature chess variants, such as [Chess Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_Attack) (5x6) and [Los Alamos Chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Alamos_chess) (6x6). Have these ever been created before, and if so, are they publicly accessible?

Answer (score 2):

Please see http://membres-lig.imag.fr/prost/MiniChessResolution/
Perhaps you should ask contact these people since they have solved Gardner and Mallet Chess and are trying to solve Los Alamos Chess which Prost believed to be a draw.